# Microsoft Identity OIDC: The audience '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is invalid

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-apicontroller, microsoft-identity-web

Trust me I tried each possible option, read all posts on stack-overflow, nothing work.

I'm using swagger UI with oauth2. whem I'm clicking on execute, always getting same response.

Error message with 401: www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"error_description="The audience '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is invalid"

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(BeararAuth)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>(Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]);
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication4", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize"),
                        TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"),
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                          {"User.Read", "User Read scope"},
                          {"access_as_user", "access APIs as user" },
                          { $"api://{Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}/access_as_user", "Application API Permissions" }
                        }
                    }
                 }
              });
         });
      }
```

Please help me on this.

I can successfully logged in to swagger using authentication flow; token is generated.

when I paste that token in https://jwt.io,

it shows me aud with value '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.

Please help me to figure out this issue. is there anything wrong I'm doing at azure ad side or there is something is missing at backend api side.

Comment: What is your bearer auth config? do you require a custom scope? (e.g. the app id in AAD). If so, you will need to add (only) scopes or resource for the target API (yours). User.Read for example is a scope for the graph API which will come back with the graph API audience instead of your app id

Comment: Yes, I have already set scope in API configuration. please correct me, you mean add scope at "Expose an API" in AAD. right?